# MCBrowserViewController has limit to 7 invitees

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I am trying to hook communication of 10 iPad's with one iPad.

MCBrowserViewController launches a view controller which will allow to select the Invitees.

It say's "Choose 1 to 7 invitees". As soon as I select One iPad in the network, it says "Choose up to 6 more invitees".

So, is the communication limited to 7 device's? How can will I be able to add 3 other devices? Is the limit related only to MCBrowserController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No device can be connected to more than seven other devices at the same time. The limit is related to bluetooth, not MCBrowserViewController .  In order to connect 10 iPads, you will need to create a chain or a tree of devices.

By constructing a chain of connected iPads I have successfully connected 12 devices. Sending messages down the chain is still reasonably fast. A binary tree of connections is better as you end up with shorter chains but managing those connections is challenging to say the least.

Comment: Chain of connection. A example really would provide a good help. I also, think if I have dynamic session type, a id which will be received from the server. So, as soon as 7 device limit is reached a new object will be created with a new session id. Idea is to have one master and other devices as slave, and all (master and salve )of them communicating to a single server. The master will broadcast message as required to slaves.